# How can I fork a repo and add as a remote with 'hub fork'?

Tags: git, github, github-hub

hub fork help says:

`fork           Make a fork of a remote repository on GitHub and add as remote`

Great, that's what I want to do.

```
hub fork https://github.com/architect/functions 
Aborted: could not find any git remote pointing to a GitHub repository
```

Well yes, that's because I want to make a fork of this repository on GitHub and add as remote, exactly as the help says.

How can I fork a repo and add as a remote with 'hub fork'?

Comment: Is the command not working? Though i usually do `hub cmd user/repo`. Typically i run fork from an already cloned repo: `hub clone user/repo; hub fork`

Comment: Yes, the error is above. I had to remove some whitespace so you might have missed it.

Comment: Right: check `man hub-fork`. I dont think it takes arguments (it probably runs from a repo)

Comment: No man pages (this isn't Unix) but that helped. Thanks!

Comment: hub *has* man pages. But fair.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble how can you see them without troff or a man command?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+man+page+viewer&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=fr-us&client=safari

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes but that's a pretty extreme solution, I'm not sure hub even ships with thee manual pages on other systems, and most  pwsh commands have their own inbuilt help that's more consistent than man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is:

```bsh
$ hub fork --help
Usage: hub fork [--no-remote] [--remote-name <REMOTE>] [--org <ORGANIZATION>]
```

Eg:

```bsh
hub fork --remote-name https://github.com/architect/functions
```

Comment: Careful here, this may just try to create a remote names after the url, not actually do the fork

Comment: @mikemaccana So sorry.  My earlier comment already got deleted. No sense in further explanation.